# Mockito cannot mock into this class

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mockito

I am trying to test my database project with unit test case with Junit and Mockito. But when i do it i am getting an error.. posting my code and stack trace. I am entirely new to testing . Kindly help

Note * - I am not using any framework

**Testing code**

*patientTest.java*

```
package com.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import com.consentServlets.SaveServlet;

public class patientTest extends Mockito{

    @Test
    public void testServlet() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);    

        when(request.getParameter("fname")).thenReturn("Rahul");
        when(request.getParameter("lname")).thenReturn("Sen");

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

        new SaveServlet().doPost(request, response);

        verify(request, atLeast(1)).getParameter("fname"); 
        writer.flush(); // it may not have been flushed yet...
        assertTrue(stringWriter.toString().contains("My expected string"));
    }
}
```

*SaveServlet.java*

```
package com.consentServlets;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/SaveServlet")
public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        //Getting the attributes from the UI
        String first_Name = request.getParameter("fname");
        String last_Name = request.getParameter("lname");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String dob = request.getParameter("dob");

        //Setting the objects to insert the achieved attributes to corresponding the columns of the table
        patient addPatient = new patient();
        addPatient.setLastName(last_Name);
        addPatient.setFirstName(first_Name);
        addPatient.setGender(gender);
        addPatient.setAge(age);
        addPatient.setDoB(dob);

        out.print(" <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css\">");
        //calling the save function from the patientDao class to execute the query
        int status=patientDao.save(addPatient);
        if(status>0){
            out.print("<p>Patient Record saved successfully!</p>");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request, response);
        }else{
            out.println("Sorry! unable to save record");
        }

        out.close();
    }

}
```

*PatientDao.java*

```
package com.consentServlets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; 

public class patientDao {
    //establishing the connection with the database
    public static Connection getConnection(){  
        Connection con=null;  
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/consent_share","root","");
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        return con;  
    }  
    public static int save(patient addPatient){  
        int status = 0;  
        //Inserting patient details from UI to Database
        try{                            
            Connection con = patientDao.getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(  
                    "insert into patient(last_name,first_name,gender,age,dob) values (?,?,?,?,?)");  
            ps.setString(1,addPatient.getLastName());  
            ps.setString(2,addPatient.getFirstName());  
            ps.setString(3,addPatient.getGender());  
            ps.setString(4,addPatient.getAge());
            ps.setString(5,addPatient.getDoB());

            status = ps.executeUpdate();  

            con.close();  
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

        return status;  
    }  

    public static patient getPatientbyId(int id){  
        patient getPatient = new patient();  
        //selecting a patient record by matching the patient_ID 
        try{ 
            Connection con = patientDao.getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from patient where patient_id=?");  
            ps.setInt(1,id);  
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
            if(rs.next()){  
                getPatient.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
                getPatient.setLastName(rs.getString(2));  
                getPatient.setFirstName(rs.getString(3));  
                getPatient.setGender(rs.getString(4));  
                getPatient.setAge(rs.getString(5));
                getPatient.setDoB(rs.getString(6)); 
            }  
            con.close();  
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  

        return getPatient;
    }  
    // Fetching all the records from table
    public static List<patient> getAllPatients(){  
        List<patient> list = new ArrayList<patient>();  

        try{  
            Connection con = patientDao.getConnection();  
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from patient");  
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
            while(rs.next()){  
                patient getAllPatients=new patient();  
                getAllPatients.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
                getAllPatients.setFirstName(rs.getString(3));  
                getAllPatients.setLastName(rs.getString(2));  
                getAllPatients.setGender(rs.getString(4));  
                getAllPatients.setAge(rs.getString(5));
                getAllPatients.setDoB(rs.getString(6));   
                list.add(getAllPatients);  
            }  
            con.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

        return list;  
    }  
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 13
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 13.0.1+9
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 13.0.1+9
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at com.test.patientTest.testServlet(patientTest.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:821)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:94)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1642)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Java version: 13
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion.ofJavaVersion(ClassFileVersion.java:135)
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion$VersionLocator$ForJava9CapableVm.locate(ClassFileVersion.java:337)
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm(ClassFileVersion.java:147)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:301)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:70)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:184)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: What version of mocktio are you using? and also what version of the bytebuddy? bytebuddy library only added support for Java 13 class files June 2019 - https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/commit/9a23e6728cce3b38f0deccfc07e03d50e2fd3816

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to you using a version of Mockito which does not yet support Java 13 because of this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Java version: 13
```

It is worth noting it is not Mockito itself that does not support Java 13 but an underlying library [byte-buddy](https://bytebuddy.net/) that is used for bytecode manipulation.

Official bytebuddy/Mockito documentation doesn't appear to indicate exactly which version adds Java 13 support but it appears to have been added in [bytebuddy 1.9.7](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.7/net/bytebuddy/ClassFileVersion.html)

Mockito [3.2.2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.2.2) updates the byte-buddy dependency to 1.10.5 so this should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...the corresponding error disappeared after updating the mockito version in the POM file.

Answer (score 0):

You might get error with a "transitive dependency".

MyJar1.jar

```
public interface ICooler
{
  public CoolerThing makeACooler(String x);

}
```

..

MyJar2.jar

```
public class CoolerThing
{
}
```

If your unit-test library tries to mock ICooler, it needs a reference to MyJar2.jar to be able to mock the method "makeACooler" because of the return type (or not shown input object type) of CoolerThing.

Note, your MyJar1 and MyJar2 may be "groupid/artifactid" items from public maven, (or private maven, or "jfrog", etc, etc).